# How to build an array with jquery and make input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, forms

Like i sayed in the title, i need to build an array and change value in form input field's
the code is:

```
<div class="row-dp">
    <div class="cel-1">Obiectiv</div>
    <div class="cel-2" id="obiectiv">macarale</div>
    <div class="cel-3">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div class="row-dp">
    <div class="cel-1">Orasul selectat</div>
    <div class="cel-2" id="orasulselectat">Bucuresti</div>
    <div class="cel-3">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

I need to take from " `<div class="cel-2"` " id to be a key and value to be value

an example

```
VAR['obiectiv'] = macarale;
VAR['orasulselectat'] = Bucuresti;
```

to transform from value in input field like

```
<input name="obiectiv" value="macarale" type="text" />
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do all the `input` elements already exist or do they need to be created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.cel-2').each(function() {
  $('input[name='+this.id+']').val($(this).text());
});
```

If you have to create the `input` elements, use this:

```
$('.cel-2').each(function() {
  $('#yourFormNameHere').append($('<input/>').prop({'name':this.id,'type':'hidden'}).val($(this).text()));
});
```

Comment: it create the input with value and id from the data at the last div

Answer (score -1):

```
 $('.row-dp').each(function(){
   if($(this).attr('id') && $(this).attr('id')!="")
    $('body').append("<input type='text' id="+$(this).attr('id')+" val="+$(this).text()+">");
 });
```